# Hilbert's fully occupied Grand Hotel

Tags: discrete-mathematics, infinity

Q: Suppose that a countably infinite number of buses, each containing a countably infinite number of guests, arrive at Hilbert's fully occupied Grand Hotel. Show that all the arriving guests can be accommodated without evicting any current guest.

The answer in the book:

Move the guest currently in Room $i$ to Room $2i+1$ for $i=1, 2, 3, ... .$ Put the $jth$ guest from the $kth$ bus into Room $2^k(2j+1)$

If we follow the way the textbook tells us, then the Room 1, 2, and 4 are empty.

This is because the 1st guest from the 1st bus is provided the Room $2^1(2*1+1)=6$, and the guest currently in Room 1 is moved to the Room $2*1+1=3.$

Hence, I think it will be more efficient if the answer is

Move the guest currently in Room $i$ to Room $2i-1$ for $i=1, 2, 3, ... .$ Put the $jth$ guest from the $kth$ bus into Room $2^k(2j-1)$

This answer fulfills all the rooms in the hotel, I think.

Is my idea correct?

Comment: Your idea looks correct. The original guests occupy all the odd numbered rooms. The guests in the $k$th bus occupy rooms with are odd multiples of $2^k$. What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Nitpicking: "I think it will be more efficient" You need a definition of "efficiency". Likely, the Hilbert Grand Hotel (or the version of it in your textbook) does not care about empty rooms.

Comment: True...the rooms are infinite

Comment: Although every natural number corresponds to a guest the hotel is not really full. It if were  , there would not be room for another guest. But in fact , there is even room for another infinite many guests. Not what I woul call a full Hotel.

Answer (score 1):

(This is a very mildly elaborated version of Amritanshu Prasad's comment)

Yes, this method completely fills the hotel.

Every number $N$ has a (unique) prime factorization $N=2^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ where each $p_i$ is odd, and hence $P=p_2^{e_2}p_3^{e_3}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ is odd. Thus for all $N$ we have the $N^\text{th}$ room occupied, containing (only) the $(P+1)/2\,^\text{th}$ person in the $e_1\,\!^\text{th}$ bus.